# Is there a way to add external DOM objects(i.e. <div>) to a stage or layer?

Tags: javascript, konvajs

I am trying to incorporate dynamic images to Konva. The plugin I am using is Apache Echarts. The container of these images is usually a div element. Is there a way to add the div to Konva layer?

Comment: If you could use an img element then it would be very simple to use the onLoad event for the image to achieve what you need.  Having said that, it might be that the echart actually placed an img or svg element into the hosting div - can you post a sample snippet that we can look at to understand the structure ?

Answer (score 1):

You can not add DOM elements into the `Konva` scene. So `<div>` can not be a child of stage or layer.

But you can a `<div>` on top of `Konva.Stage` with absolute position and control it manully.

There is a demo of adding `<textarea>` on top of the canvas: https://konvajs.org/docs/sandbox/Editable_Text.html

Comment: thanks I have done this, but I wish the on top div can resize along with my layer, like it is a child of layer. Is there any methods can realize this?

Comment: Not automatically. You have to resize it manually when you change the layer.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at this [example echart](https://www.echartsjs.com/examples/en/editor.html?c=line-simple) using inspect in the browser, it can be seen that echarts inserts a canvas element - here is a copy of the DOM, notice the canvas element.

```
<div id="chart-panel" class="right-panel" _echarts_instance_="ec_1573495851087"
    style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent; user-select: none;">
    <div
        style="position: relative; overflow: hidden; width: 1132px; height: 569px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; border-width: 0px; cursor: default;">
        <canvas data-zr-dom-id="zr_0" width="1132" height="569"
            style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 1132px; height: 569px; user-select: none; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); padding: 0px; margin: 0px; border-width: 0px;"></canvas>
    </div>
</div>
```

Therefore you could position a host div off screen and use the canvas.toDataURL method of that echarts canvas to grab the image and then give that to a Konva image object. Looking at the echarts API there are event triggers that you could listen for so as to know when to execute. So this turns the issue into 'how to draw the contents of canvas A into an image shape on canvas B'.

However, I note that there are animations which are possibly part of what you would want to maintain for good UX, and in that case you may want to revert to keeping the plain HTML div and positioning it above the Konva canvas, etc, as per @lavrton's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can add html element to konvajs:

```
handleStageMouseDown(e) {
  // clicked on stage
  var textarea = document.createElement('textarea');
  document.body.appendChild(textarea);
  textarea.value = "simple text area on konvajs";
  textarea.style.position = 'absolute';
  textarea.style.top = e.target.pointerPos.y + 'px';
  textarea.style.left = e.target.pointerPos.x + 'px';
}
```